# How to integrate filepond upload with octobercms?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, filepond

I really love the interface of filepond but having a hard time getting the uploaded images in backend. My code works for normal file input.

I currently have this in my default.htm

```
<input type="file" 
    class="filepond"
    name="allimages[]" 
    multiple 
    data-max-file-size="3MB"
    data-max-files="12">
```

PostForm.php to handle the file.

```
 $advert->allimage = Input::file('allimage');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser limitation. You can only POST file objects when sending data with `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` but that means you have to submit your form asynchronously.

> When we want to submit files along with the classic form post we run into a serious browser limitation. The file input field is the only field available to submit files to a server but its value cannot be set. The file input field value can only be modified by the user by manually adding files (in one action).

To work around this you can use the [File Encode plugin](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/file-encode/), which encodes the files as base64 data strings and sends those to the server.

**Submitting forms with very large base64 encoded strings can result in browsers running out of memory (especially on mobile devices). Server side security software might also tag a big form post as insecure and prevent the submit from succeeding.**

Comment: Is there another work around to it? Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: You either encode the file and decode it on the server, or you send it asynchronously as a file object using `fetch` or `XMLHttpRquest`

Comment: Do you have an example of that?